# Tech stack for a FP&A solution

Tags: javascript, api, architecture, data-modeling, webdatarocks

> Maybe I'm sailing in deep water and one of you could throw me a life preserver  to better understand what I want to ask.
> I have received a request to identify the components that a solution like the one in the image could use, this is an FP&A solution of which there are several such as:
>
> https://www.cubesoftware.com
> https://www.anaplan.com/
> https://www.datarails.com/
>
> [image]
>
> It is evident that in these solutions there are connectors for the different services that export data from these to a "model" or maybe a data warehouse  that possibly has the data structure of these services. What may be in that model is a black box for me and I would like to know if Any of you have worked with a similar project that could tell me what is possibly in the model layer, which for the purposes I have identified in column 2 of the image.
>
> For the column 3 part I understand there are components like:
>
> [https://www.webdatarocks.com/](https://www.webdatarocks.com/demos/javascript-pivot-grid-demo/)
>
> **Waiting for an answer from any of you my questions are:**
>
> What kind of technology is used in a solution like this?
>
> What components could be used for column 2
>
> What components could be used for column 3
>
> What other options exist for column 3

Answer (score 1):

You could use Flexmonster for data visualization in column 3 as well. Flexmonster also has a special tool to aggregate the data, as shown in column 2, called Flexmonster Data Server, or even custom data source API protocol so you could easily write the server for column 2 by yourself.

Comment: thank you, this is a piece of good information to note.